# How to remove special character from child

Tags: jquery

I want to remove comma(,) from second child. In `console.log()` remove comma perfectly but in tag comma is not removed

Here down is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var child = $("span").children()[1];
   $(child).html().replace(/,/g , ''); // in second child comma is not removed
   console.log($(child).html().replace(/,/g , '')); // remove comma perfectly
});
```

```css
li { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span>
    <li>One, </li>
    <li>Two,</li>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output:

```
One, Two
```

Comment: `replace` returns a new String, it does not edit in place.

Comment: `.html()` _gets_ the HTML. To _set_ the HTML, you can call it like `.html('text')`. So you can do `$(child).html($(child).html().replace(/,/g , ''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the value to the DOM Element

```
$(child).html($(child).html().replace(/,/g , ''));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var child = $("span").children()[1];
   $(child).html($(child).html().replace(/,/g , '')); // You must set the value to the DOM
   console.log($(child).html().replace(/,/g , '')); // remove comma perfectly
});
```

```css
li { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span>
    <li>One, </li>
    <li>Two,</li>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```